# How can I play each type of video in a view in android

Tags: android, video

I am working on an android application and my application is having a functionality to upload multiple type of videos in app. The videos can be from any sources like Youtube, Vimeo or can be uploaded from device. So, I want to play each type of videos in my application whether they are uploaded from any type of resources.

If I use VideoView, it supports only some of the extensions and it can't play youtube and viemo uploaded videos as well. I have to use Webview to play youtube and vimeo videos.

Is there any view which can play all type of videos or can someone help me in creating a video player view which can play each type of video.

I don't have much idea about videoview, please help me if anyone know about this so that I can create a view which can play all type if video formats.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: It's not a simple task, check this sample https://github.com/google/grafika

Comment: I'd suggest to narrow your question: share your code, ask how do I implement this specifically for, say, YouTube (and also show us some efforts of your own to implement this). For now, this is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

There seems no universal video player for all video sources/types.

- The Android built-in VideoView can play **rtsp** and **HLS** streams, take a look at [Android: How to play RTSP or HLS video streams](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/09/19/android-how-to-play-rtsp-or-hls-video-streams/)
- To play **rtmp** video streams in Android, you can use a number of libraries such as Vitamio: refer to [Android: How to play RTMP video streams](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/09/20/android-how-to-play-rtmp-video-streams/)
- The VideoView used to be able to play **youtube** videos, but now you cannot. You need to use YouTube Android Player API now. Refer to [Android development: Play Youtube video in your app, “Can’t play this video” and troubleshooting](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/android-development-play-youtube-video-in-your-app-cant-play-this-video-and-troubleshooting/) instead.